# How do I "activate" a button on the GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, button

By now, I already know my code is flawed. I just want to know *why* it's flawed. I want to activate the "webButton" so that when it gets clicked, it prints a message on the console that reads "This opens Mozilla Firefox."

```
package smartphone;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Smartphone implements ActionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
{
{
JFrame container = new JFrame();

container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

Scanner daniel = new Scanner(System.in);

JButton webButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Firefox.png"));
JButton phoButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Facebook.png"));
JButton texButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Phone.png"));
JButton setButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Settings.png"));
JButton smsButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("sms.png"));


container.setTitle("Smartphone Interface!");
container.setSize(240,340);
container.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

container.add(setButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
container.add(webButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
container.add(texButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
container.add(phoButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
container.add(smsButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
container.setVisible(true);


    webButton.addActionListener(instanceofSmartphone);

    }

    }
    }
     }
```

Comment: Is this **android** code? There is **no evidence** that it is.

Comment: remove the Android tag, and add the Swing tag for example

Comment: What part of your question cannot be answered by reading the button [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#abstractbutton)

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

```
    webButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
        }
    });
```

If you want to use the ActionListener interface then, implement it in your Frame class and then replace that instanceOfSmartphone with

```
webButton.addActionListener(this);
```

And put this outside the method

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == webButton) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to excuse me because I'm still a novice, but is that block of code supposed to go directly at the bottom? And how can I print out a statement with webButton after that?

Comment: inside the if. The first block of code you can use it instead of webButton.addActionListener(instanceofSmartphone); The second block, just leave everything as it is, but replace the instanceofSmartphone as I put in the edited answer. Then put the second block outside of any method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the actionPerformed method.  An example follows.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("This method opens Mozilla Firefox.");
}
```

Additionally, you need to change how you add the action listener to the following.

```
webButton.addActionListener(this);
```

There are also a number of other issues.  Here is a modified version of your code to get it working but far from perfect or what you will want in the end.  I strongly recommend you walk through all of the tutorials in order at the below website.  It doesn't get any easier than what they have.  Also, if your not already using it, you should try Netbeans or some other IDE.  It give you feedback that may help while you are starting out.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

```
package smartphone;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Smartphone extends Frame implements ActionListener {
    static JButton webButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Firefox.png"));
    static JButton phoButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Facebook.png"));
    static JButton texButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Phone.png"));
    static JButton setButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("Settings.png"));
    static JButton smsButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("sms.png"));

    Smartphone(){
       webButton.addActionListener(this);       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Smartphone container = new Smartphone();

        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Scanner daniel = new Scanner(System.in);

        container.setTitle("Smartphone Interface!");
        container.setSize(240, 340);

        container.add(setButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        container.add(webButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        container.add(texButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        container.add(phoButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        container.add(smsButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        container.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("This opens a Firefox Webbrowser.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've visited that exact page many times. It's still too technical for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `ActionListener` to the buttons INSIDE of the constructor: `buttonName.addActionListener(this);`.
Then you need to create the following method:

    `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
         Object control = event.getSource();
         if (control == buttonName) {
              //Run code...
         }
    }`